# Can I use props in computed property to bind a css class?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-props

Is it possible to use the props inside a computed property, in some other way?

When I do this, it add the class 'foo' (name of the props), instead the wanted 'fa-foo' (or other value, if props were set).

Both works, if I only bind one of them, directly in the markup.

```
props: {
  foo: {
    type: String,
    default: 'fa-foo'
  }
},

computed: {
  classObject: function () {
    return {
      foo: true,
      'text-danger': true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you need to add it, i.e `foo: this.foo,`, adding a boolean value to some arbitrary object with the same property key won't magically pull it from the props

Comment: How can this work, the right side is supposed to be a true/false value right? If you write "this.foo", you will get a truthy value from the string it self. I need that string to show up in the DOM as a css class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object syntax of class bindings applies the *key* as the class name when the value is truthy. Since the computed prop return value includes `{ foo: true }`, the `"foo"` class is applied.

To set the value of the `foo` prop as the class name, you can use `this.foo` as the key with brackets:

```js
computed: {
  classObject: function () {
    return {
      [this.foo]: true,
      'text-danger': true
    }
  }
}
```

Class bindings also allow an array of strings and objects, so the computed prop could also be written as:

```js
computed: {
  classObject: function () {
    return [
      this.foo,
      {
        'text-danger': true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

...or just an array of strings:

```js
computed: {
  classObject: function () {
    return [
      this.foo,
      'text-danger',
    ]
  }
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-class-bindings?file=src/App.vue)

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `this.foo` to access the prop, because of the different scopes